# Evaluation of double integral using substitution

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

Evaluate $$\int_0^1 dz \int_0^1 du \frac{u^{1+\alpha} (1-z)^{\alpha} z}{(b + z) (1-uz)},$$ for $b$ a constant.
I am using the substitution $w=u(1-z)$ which gives $$\int_0^1 dz \int_0^{1-z} dw \frac{w^{\alpha}wz}{(b+z)(1-z - wz)} = \int_0^1dw \int_0^{1-w}dz \frac{w^{\alpha}wz}{(b+z)(1-z - wz)}$$ since the domain of integration is interior of triangle.

The substitution was a suggestion by a tutor in my class but I don't think it helped because I still have the coupled term $wz$. Is that the right conclusion to make?

Comment: at least the inner integral is elementary now, have you checked what happens afterwards?

Comment: Hi @tired, hmm I don't see why the inner integral is elementary now, doesn't the coupled term $wz$ complicate things?

Comment: it will give a combination of logs and polynomials. the problem is that the outer integral is non-trivial

Comment: Are you sure the substitution doesn't give $\int_0^1 dz \int_0^{1-z} dw \frac{w^{\alpha}wz}{{\color{red}{(1+z)}(b+z)(1-z - wz)}}$? Anyway, I'm thinking about partial fraction decomposition on the last integral you've written...

Comment: Also are $\alpha,b >0 $ or is all we know is that they are (real) constants?

Comment: @zahbaz: I got a factor of $w/(1-z)$ when I subbed in for $u$ on the numerator but this was cancelled by a $(1-z)$ coming from replacing $1-uz$ in terms of $w$ and $z$. (as far as I can see). And yes, they are just real constants.

Comment: A partial fraction decomposition does indeed give logs and polynomials but the resulting integral is $$\int_0^1 dw \frac{w^{\alpha+1}}{1+b(1+w)} \left(1-w-b\ln(1+1/b-w/b)-2\ln w\right),$$ The first two terms look like hypergeometrics but the last two terms I am not sure.

Comment: Do you think integration by parts would help with the above?

Comment: ? Is an integral like $$\int_0^1 dw \frac{w^{\alpha+1} \ln(b+1-w)}{1+b(1+w)}$$ really non trivial? I mean I think it should be hypergeometric but I can't see how to transform it into one